# How to grab 2 data points from the beginning and end of a CSV file and subtract them using command line?

Tags: command-line, csv

I was able to script the following line to output just the column I needed. I can't seem to grab the first number, `56485.65`, and the last, `56498.2`, to subtract the two and output the results, though.

```
$ tail +7  2022-11-13.csv | sed "12 d"| cut  -d ";" -f 9
56485.65
56485.65
56485.65
56485.65
56485.65
56485.65
56485.65

56497.53
56497.72
56497.92
56497.99
56498.03
56498.07
56498.15
56498.2
```

Below is a shortened version of the CSV file. I cut out a chunk in the middle to shorten it up.

```
$ cat 2022-11-13.csv 
CSV-Export;Version: 1.01;Separator: Semicolon

;Emgncy03;Emgncy03;Emgncy03;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A;WRHU0U5A
;2120203458;2120203458;2120203458;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843;2120048843
TimeStamp;ErrCode1;ErrCode2;ErrCode3;A.Ms.Amp;A.Ms.Vol;A.Ms.Watt;Error;E-Total;GridMs.Hz;GridMs.PhV.phsA;GridMs.PhV.phsB;GridMs.PhV.phsC;Inv.TmpLimStt;MainModel;Mode;Mt.TotOpTmh;Mt.TotTmh;Op.EvtCntUsr;Op.EvtNo;Op.GriSwStt;Op.TmsRmg;Pac;Serial Number
hh:mm;;;;A;V;W;;kWh;Hz;V;V;V;;;;h;h;;;;s;W;
07:05;;;;0;352.26;0;0: -------;56485.65;59.97;245.92;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;7: Warten;42937.23;45042.04;432;0;1: Opn;0;0;2120048843
07:10;;;;0;370.58;0;0: -------;56485.65;59.98;244.48;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;7: Warten;42937.23;45042.13;432;0;1: Opn;0;0;2120048843
07:15;;;;0;399.37;0;0: -------;56485.65;59.99;244.09;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;7: Warten;42937.23;45042.21;432;0;1: Opn;0;0;2120048843
07:20;;;;0;426.34;0;0: -------;56485.65;59.99;245.07;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;7: Warten;42937.23;45042.29;432;0;1: Opn;0;0;2120048843
07:25;;;;0.06;394.03;21.97;0: -------;56485.65;59.99;245.34;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;1: MPP;42937.28;45042.37;432;0;2: Cls;0;12.86;2120048843
07:30;;;;0.12;360.71;41;0: -------;56485.65;59.99;245.56;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;1: MPP;42937.36;45042.46;432;0;2: Cls;0;26.55;2120048843
------  cut out chunk ----------
14:25;;;;6.3;403.19;2538.86;0: -------;56497.53;60;251.18;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;1: MPP;42944.28;45049.38;432;0;2: Cls;0;2431.1;2120048843
14:30;;;;6;405.64;2430.86;0: -------;56497.72;60;250.99;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;1: MPP;42944.36;45049.46;432;0;2: Cls;0;2327.17;2120048843
14:35;;;;6.35;385.46;2444.54;0: -------;56497.92;59.98;250.69;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;1: MPP;42944.45;45049.54;432;0;2: Cls;0;2337.07;2120048843
14:40;;;;2.35;391.32;928.54;0: -------;56497.99;59.99;247.68;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;1: MPP;42944.53;45049.63;432;0;2: Cls;0;873.39;2120048843
14:45;;;;1.3;400.13;519.54;0: -------;56498.03;59.99;247.57;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;1: MPP;42944.61;45049.71;432;0;2: Cls;0;489.62;2120048843
14:50;;;;1.19;402.03;478.04;0: -------;56498.07;60.02;247.29;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;1: MPP;42944.7;45049.79;432;0;2: Cls;0;450.39;2120048843
14:55;;;;2.28;419.46;956.9;0: -------;56498.15;60.01;248.64;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;1: MPP;42944.78;45049.88;432;0;2: Cls;0;914.59;2120048843
15:00;;;;1.46;408.06;593.76;0: -------;56498.2;59.99;247.76;0;0;1: NoneDrt;1: Solar-WR;1: MPP;42944.86;45049.96;432;0;2: Cls;0;562.93;2120048843
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to do that. You don't need to output all lines from line 7 to the end. You just need to get the value of the 9th column of line 7 and the  9th column of the last line and subtract them as follows:

```
awk -F ";" 'NR==7 {a=$9}; END {print $9 - a}' 2022-11-13.csv
```

The output is:

```
12.55
```

**Explanation**

- `-F ";"`: use `;` as the field separator.
- `NR==7 {a=$9}`: go to the 7th line (`NR==7`) and store the value of the 9th column (`$9`) to the variable `a` (`a=$9`).
- `END {print $9 - a}`: subtract the value of variable `a` from the 9th column of the last line and print the result.